# IPFS public node in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, coreos, ipfs

I'm attempting to set up an [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) server on my home network. I have a [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) box that I'd like to get up and running with it. Since CoreOS focuses on Docker containers, that's the setup I've got.

I have got it working such that I can spin up a Docker container running the daemon:

```
docker run --name ipfs.service \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 4001:4001 -p 5001:5001 \
  ipfs/go-ipfs:v0.4.14
```

And I've logged into the running container (`docker exec -it ipfs.service sh`) and updated the "Addresses.Gateway" option to be "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080".

On startup, the log does show:

```
API server listening on /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready
```

Now, I'd like to be able to browse the IPFS content from another workstation on my home network. However, navigating to `http://192.168.0.100:8080/ipfs/QmW2WQi7j6c7UgJTarActp7tDNikE4B2qXtFCfLPdsgaTQ/cat.jpg` (where my CoreOS has a local IP address of `192.168.0.100`), I get a "Connection Refused" error in Chrome.

Using SSH tunneling I can get access to the IPFS content (forwarding the server 8080 port to my local workstation), so I know that the IPFS server is serving something to the outer CoreOS layer at least.

But how to get it one layer further? I'm unsure if this is a CoreOS configuration error or an IPFS daemon configuration error. How can I further troubleshoot where this connection is being dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be an issue with the IPFS version; updating to the latest version of IPFS caused the issue to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a docker thing as everything looks OK on the IPFS-configuration side of things.

When running your docker container, try running it with `docker run ... -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080` instead of just `-p 8080:8080`. I think docker by default binds `8080:8080` to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.